# Capturing increased uncertainty as data changes

Tags: bayesian, entropy, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, uncertainty

I'm experimenting with quantifying uncertainty in data from a Bernoulli distribution by measuring the likelihood the p parameter using the beta distribution. Specifically, I'd like to show how uncertainty changes over time as you update the alpha and beta priors of beta distribution with data from a Bernoulli distribution (let's say p=0.75).

It seems that entropy will always decrease as new data in incorporated into the alpha and beta params and that makes sense to me. However, I want to show entropy increasing if I start updating alpha and beta with data from a Bernoulli distribution with a different p parameter (let's say p=0.33). Just updating alpha and beta with data from the new distribution will shift my posterior, but will also compress it. I want the posterior to widen as I incorporate data from a different distribution. What would be the best way to accomplish that? I'm not a stats expert so let me know if I'm way off in what I'm trying to accomplish.